# Embedded JBPM 6.4 TO RHPAM 7.4 Rest api migration

Tags: jboss7.x, jbpm, redhat-bpm

Am in a project that requires the migration of jbpm 6.4 to rhpam 7.5 version.

In the current version we use embedded jbpm as in everything is added as dependency and the war file is deployed into the server.

We are planning to migrate to rhpam to use it as an execution server and thus the process models will be  there and we use rest api to call them. Please help me with where to start or any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating from BPMS 6.4 to RHPAM 7 is much easier then migrating from BxMS 5 to RHPAM 7. Few things you need to ensure while migrating the processes.

1. Make a copy of the database and upgrade the database schema compatible to RHPAM 7 as few schema changes happened between BxMS 6 and RHPAM 7.
2. Since, your current project is embedded architecture so you need to import all assets manually to B-C created project. Try to fix all issues here and there after importing the assets like signal ref, gateways etc. Validate the project, build and deploy.
3. If you’re migrating the active processes, make sure the process definitions in session and database doesn’t differ. That means if you want to fix .bpmn files issues after importing, make sure that you always create new kjar and deploy as new kiecontainer otherwise you will get load of class cast exceptions while testing active records.

Answer (score 0):

When I did the migration, I went towards Spring boot version.
You should follow the RHPAM migration guide and setup a new RHPAM instance.
Start moving your files over there. If you use Spring boot, there is much more involved.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_process_automation_manager/7.0/html-single/migrating_from_red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite_6.4_to_red_hat_process_automation_manager_7.0/

I've done a complete rhpam 6.4 to rhpam 7 spring boot migration for my company.